# Rails and Paperclip Errno::EACCES Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm stuck with this for days. I keep getting this error trying to upload image:

**Errno::EACCES in MyController#create**

```
Permission denied - c:\"Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.9-Q16"/convert "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110522-5332-1e34ydw.jpg[0]" -resize "848x608!" "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110522-5332-1e34ydw20110522-5332-z5iv1g" 2>NUL
```

when I copy this line above to the command line and run it, it works - no permission denied error. What should I do to allow ruby do it?

I'm running on:

**Windows 7**

**WEBrick 1.3.1**

**ruby 1.9.2p180** (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

**rails (3.0.7)**

**Paperclip**  - I've tried versions **2.3.11, 2.3.4, and 2.3.6, and 2.3.10** but I still keep getting the same error.

I've googled a lot for a solution and aplied the tempfile fsync fix found on [http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/11/2/goodbye-attachment_fu-hello-paperclip][1]

and also 
the file.mv replacement with copy and delete, in tempfile, that looked like the solution, but that doesn't help. These fixes besides seems to be in the newer versions of paperclip by default.

Of course I restarted webrick allways I made any changes.

The console info by server, when this problem rises:

```
Started POST "/admin/front_campaigns" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-22 12:35:10 +0200
  Processing by FrontCampaignsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ôťô", 

"authenticity_token"=>"DwX4TRaU1wGOleyxhjzpcmmg2m9pbtzLOj1WOa48cXc=", "front_campaign"=>
{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41bd508 @original_filename="home1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"front_campaign
[picture]\"; filename=\"home1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20110522-5292-2recc
l>>, "name"=>"", "description"=>"", "web"=>"", "position_x"=>"1", "position_y"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Front campaign"}
[paperclip] c:\"Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.9-Q16"/identify -format %wx%h "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110522-5292-ks7a6r.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
[paperclip] c:\"Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.9-Q16"/convert "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110522-5292-ks7a6r.jpg[0]" -resize "848x608!" "C:
/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110522-5292-ks7a6r20110522-5292-17svo7l" 2>NUL
Completed   in 360ms

Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - c:\"Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.9-Q16"/convert "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110522-5292-ks7a6r.jpg[0]"
 -resize "848x608!" "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110522-5292-ks7a6r20110522-5292-17svo7l" 2>NUL):
  app/controllers/front_campaigns_controller.rb:44:in `new'
  app/controllers/front_campaigns_controller.rb:44:in `create'

/sorry for the formating, I was unable to get a nicer copy of windows commandline/

full trace:

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/command_line.rb:27:in `run'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip.rb:104:in `run'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb:61:in `make'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in `make'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:344:in `block (2 levels) in post_process_styles'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:343:in `each'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:343:in `inject'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:343:in `block in post_process_styles'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:339:in `each'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:339:in `post_process_styles'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:333:in `block (2 levels) in post_process'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_picture_post_process_callbacks'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/callback_compatability.rb:54:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:332:in `block in post_process'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_post_process_callbacks'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/callback_compatability.rb:54:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:331:in `post_process'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:110:in `assign'

paperclip (2.3.10) lib/paperclip.rb:252:in `block in has_attached_file'

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:1559:in `block in attributes='

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:1555:in `each'

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:1555:in `attributes='

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/base.rb:1407:in `initialize'

app/controllers/front_campaigns_controller.rb:44:in `new'

app/controllers/front_campaigns_controller.rb:44:in `create'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `_run__41168123__process_action__129617020__callbacks'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in 
process_action'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispa
tch'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'

rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'

rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'

rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'

rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'

rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'

rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in 
`cache'

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'

activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'

rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'

railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'

rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'

activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'

rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'

<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'

rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'

actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'

railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'

railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'

railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'

rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'

rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

the request parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",

 "authenticity_token"=>"DwX4TRaU1wGOleyxhjzpcmmg2m9pbtzLOj1WOa48cXc=",

 "front_campaign"=>{"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3fe1b10 
@original_filename="home1.jpg",

 @content_type="image/jpeg",

 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"front_campaign[picture]\"; filename=\"home1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",

 @tempfile = File:C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20110522-4824-1tyjwrv>, // this tempfile is created

 "name"=>""},

 "commit"=>"Create Front campaign"}
```

Comment: have you tried to run WebBrick as administrator? (start the terminal as administrator and then run webbrick) Maybe Ruby is not allowed to access your Program Files directory or may not create files in your temporary folder.

Comment: thanks, I tried, but it didn't help. If I understund the process right, than the program files folder must be accessible, because the identify command worked correctly. Then the convert command didn't. The tempfile is actually created, when I try manually acces the tempfile in local it exists.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I finally found a solution, it was kinda stupid:

I reinstalled the ImageMagick, and instead of using the default folder in Program Files, I picked folder `C:\im`, than I set the

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:\\im"
```

in `development.rb` and now it works perfectly, with and without the styles options.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.